# When I retrieve data from the API but Its show as object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I retrieve data from the API "firstname" and "lastname" values are showing. But "jobTitle" value is not showing in the table but it shows as an array in the console box. Please help me to solve that

Here is the **visibility.ts** file:

```
export class VisibilityComponent implements OnInit {
  pmDetails1: IEmployee[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe((pmDetails1: IEmployee[]) => {
      this.pmDetails1 = pmDetails1;
       console.log(pmDetails1);
       console.log(pmDetails1[0].jobTitle);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML file

```
<div>
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="dialogbox-viewport">
            <table class="table table-light" style="border: 1px solid">
              <thead style="background-color: aqua">
                <tr>
                  <th>Select</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let p of pmDetails1">
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{p.firstName}}" (change) = "onSelectedEmployee($event)" [checked]="check" /> 
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ p.firstName }} {{ p.lastName }}</td>
                  <td>{{ p.jobTitle }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
        </div>
```

Here is the **IEmployee.ts** file

```
export interface IEmployee {
    userId: any;
    firstName: string;
    jobTitle: any;
    lastName: String;
}
```

Here is the output:

![enter image description here][1]

Here is the "console.log(pmDetails1)"

![enter image description here][2]

Here is the "console.log(pmDetails[0].jobTitles)"

[image]

I want to show jobTitlesName in the Role column in the table. I am a beginner to Angular. Please help me to do

Comment: Who creates that object in the backend? according to your images `jobTitles` is not an array, but a object with several properties of its own. So how do you want to stringify that object for your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your HTML file.

```
<td>{{ p.jobTitle.jobTitleName }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is okay, the only problem is that the property `jobTitle` is an `Object`

You have 3 available options (Or More)

### Option 1

Return the value as a string from the backend;
This will mean we can amend your interface to

```typescript
    export interface IEmployee {
        userId: any;
        firstName: string;
        jobTitle: string;
        lastName: String;

    }
```

### Option 2

Change interface to reflect the `Object` from the backend

```typescript
    export interface IEmployee {
        userId: any;
        firstName: string;
        jobTitle: { jobTitleName: string; jobTitleId: number };
        lastName: String;

    }
```

In your html you can now use this as below. This approach has been stated by @shehanpathirathna

```html
<td>{{ p.jobTitle.jobTitleName }}</td>
```

### Option 3

Use `map` to produce a new Object with the desired structure

```typescript
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    export class VisibilityComponent implements OnInit {
      pmDetails1: IEmployee[];

      constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getAllUsers().pipe(
           map(employeea => employees.map(
              (employee) => ({...employee, jobTitle: jobTitle.jobTitleName })
           ))
        ).subscribe((pmDetails1: IEmployee[]) => {
          this.pmDetails1 = pmDetails1;
           console.log(pmDetails1);
           console.log(pmDetails1[0].jobTitle);
        });
      }
    }
```

This option is probably an overkill for this specific situation but can be very helpful if the Object gets more complex

Comment: I was also writing the same answer, but Owen Kelvin posted it before me. It is the perfect solution for this issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
export class VisibilityComponent implements OnInit {
  pmDetails1: IEmployee[];
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.pmDetails1 = data;
       console.log(pmDetails1);
       console.log(pmDetails1[0].jobTitle);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what? why? Just because you call a carrot a banana, that doesn't change what it is.

Comment: in HTML `<td>{{p.jobTitle.jobTitleName}}</td>`